# Win Forms DataGridView Horizontal ScrollBar

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

Is it possible to show **permanently** the horizontal scroll bar of a DataGridView in Windows Forms 2.0. Like we can do in the horizontal scroll bar of a Panel.

Currently, the Horizontal ScrollBar is visible only when the total sum of widths of the columns is bigger than the DataGridView width. But I want this scroll bar to be always visible.

Thanks

Comment: No.  The ScrollBars property only allows hiding them, not forcing them to show.  The internals of calculating whether or not the scrollbar is needed is far too complication and cannot be messed with.  A dummy column is your only real option.

Answer (score 2):

As it was mentioned in comments DataGridView controls its scrollbars and always wants to hide them if there is no need in viewing them, e.g. all cells fit into grid's visible area.

However, there is a way to force DataGridView to show its scroll bars using reflection, though it's a hack and I wouldn't recommend doing this. Below is an example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // assuming dataGridView1 is a DataGridView control placed on the Form1 form
    PropertyInfo property = dataGridView1.GetType().GetProperty(
        "HorizontalScrollBar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (property != null)
    {
        ScrollBar scrollbar = (ScrollBar)property.GetValue(dataGridView1, null);
        scrollbar.Visible = true;
        scrollbar.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(ScrollBar_VisibleChanged);
    }
}

void ScrollBar_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FieldInfo field = dataGridView1.GetType().GetField(
        "layout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (field != null)
    {
        object layoutData = field.GetValue(dataGridView1);
        FieldInfo insideField = layoutData.GetType().GetField(
            "Inside", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)insideField.GetValue(layoutData); 

        ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar)sender;
        scrollBar.Visible = true;
        scrollBar.SetBounds(
            rect.Left, rect.Height - scrollBar.Height + 1,
            rect.Width, scrollBar.Height);
    }
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Well, although it did show the scroll, it made the rectangle beneath to be hidden.

Comment: So finally I just added a dummy field which is very long (frozen), and makes the H scroll bar to be visible constantly.